# How to use sikuli with latest apple safari driver

Tags: sikuli, safaridriver, selenium3

i am using sikuli along with selenium ... with latest selenium 3.0.1 safaridriver, user interations are disabled and it throws popup window "This safari window is remotely controlled by an automated test".

Any idea on how to disable that pop-up window or perform sikuli interactions based on image like click in safari browser?

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://sites.google.com/site/appleclubfhs/support/advice-and-articles/browser-popup-hijack-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/

Is this the popup you are seeing?

[image]

If so it may not yet be possible to use Sikuli against Safari 10+.  The article linked above explains what is happening and why.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to got into Develop and Allow Remote Automation?

[image]